# Mount an ssh file system automatically after network connection has been established and after login

Tags: networking, mount, sshfs

I use the following command to mount a file system over ssh:

```
sshfs mother:/netvol /netvol
```

This uses a public/private key pair for authentication, one that resides within my `home` directory. As such, I am required to be logged in before the mount can occur.

Furthermore, the network connection that gives access to `mother` requires a certificate -- stored within my `home` -- and user credentials, that I let the Network Manager store for me. The connection to the network is established -- automatically -- a few seconds after login.

How can I have the mount be performed automatically? Due to the considerations outlined above, I cannot just use the `fstab` or put the line `sshfs mother:/netvol /netvol` in `.profile`.

I am on **Ubuntu 15.10**.